# What does EventSystem.currentSelectedGameObject consider the current object to be?

Tags: unity, c#

I've been working with UI in my project as of late and I can't figure out what Unity's event system is supposed to return for `currentSelectedGameObject`.

```
if (EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject != null)
{
    Debug.Log(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name);
}
```

With the code above I figured that it should return something when I'm moving the mouse across the various UI elements. Unity's documentation appears to be poor on this function stating:

> The GameObject currently considered active by the `EventSystem`.

maybe I'm just being stupid but does anyone know what triggers `currentSelectedGameObject`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `currentSelectedGameObject` is not updated by simple mouse-over, as far as I'm aware.

Instead, it's more analogous to moving through an interface with tab. In the Unity UI system, you can move around between buttons with the keyboard. I think you'll find that behaves as expected.

If you want to know what UI object the mouse is over, I believe you'll need to implement that manually.

<sup>Quoting from: [(4.6 UI) How to detect mouse over on button on answers.unity3d.com](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/783279/46-ui-how-to-detect-mouse-over-on-button.html).</sup>

> - Add an event trigger component to your button game object.
> - Click on <kbd>Add New</kbd> button and select `PointerEnter`.
> - Now click on <kbd>+</kbd> button to add a new item to the list of event of type `PointerEnter(BaseEventData)`.
> - Select the object containing your script.
> - Now select the function to be called from the list of functions.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. why not mention that in the documentation though...

Comment: Agreed - it is an odd oversight in the docs, with broken links and all that lovely jazz. I think it's a consequence of the EventSystem existing before the 4.6 UI update, so there's misalignment between them.

Comment: I talked to one of the documentation staff at a Unity conference about this and it was noted down. So hopefully they will look at this soon.