# Issue with button clicked by mouse?

Tags: unity, gui

I have panel with some images and buttons. when I click on a button with "gold" name it works, and if I click on any thing other I got error //NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object//

```
public GameObject gold; 

void Update()
{   

   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
        {
        gold = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject; // error line
        if (gold.GetComponent<Button>().name == "Gold")
        {
        print (" you got some gold ^-^");
        }
        else
        {
            gold = null;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Most likely, the `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject` does not have a button. You might want to check that first.

Comment: OK, if doesn't have a button, gold = null. why it request to set object !?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113980/what-does-eventsystem-currentselectedgameobject-consider-the-current-object-to-b

Comment: because I have around 90 buttons in my canvas, I'm trying to avoid this method. My script will do this job but this stupid error blocking me.

Comment: Did you try to check if `EventSystem.current` is null before getting the `currentSelectedGameObject`? From what I could gather, maybe if you click on something else, and it's not part of the UI, maybe at that moment the `current` is not active?

Comment: yes. its null. and way you marked my topic as duplicated !. I'm talking about different method.

Comment: The issue is essentially that you have a nullreference exception, and we close nullreference exceptions issues as duplicate of that one. If that's not it, it's not clear what you're after.